# how python pass two dataframe as argument into one function with the function tools partial?

Tags: python, partial, functools

When pass two dataframe obj into the func.It goes right.
While using partial, it says:

```
TypeError: fall() got multiple values for argument 'dfn'
```

Here is the test code?
Any one knows why?

```
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool 
import pandas as pd

def fall(dfn,x):
    return dfn,x


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df=pd.DataFrame([['a'],['b']])
    dfxn=pd.DataFrame([['c'],['d']])

    print(fall(dfxn,df))
    f=partial(fall,dfn=dfxn)
    print(f(df))
```

In addtion, It goes right when

```
f=partial(fall,x=dfxn)
print(f(df))
```

Comment: It's not working for the same reason `fall(dfxn, dfn=df)` won't work, there is both a positional and keyword argument for dfn. Try changing the last line to `print(f(x=df))`.

Comment: Then if I want to push the f=partial(fall,dfn=dfxn) into a multiprocess pool. 
How shall I call it ?

Comment: <pre><code>
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool 
import pandas as pd

def fall(dfn,x):
    return dfn,x


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df=pd.DataFrame([['a'],['b']])
    dfxn=pd.DataFrame([['c'],['d']])
    pool=Pool(2)
    f=partial(fall,dfn=dfxn)
    pool.map(f,[df,df])  #how to put df into f(x)? it can only send df to first argument to dfn?
    
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
</code></pre>

Comment: `pool.map(f,[df,df])` or `pool.map(f,x=[df,df])` may raise errors.

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to switch the argument order so your partial application can use positional arguments. Otherwise you can do the partial with a lambda instead.